# How to set Visibility for a button from another activity in android

Tags: android, button, visibility

I'm developing an android application in which I'm trying to set visiblity for button
Here there are two activities

1) Activity2 which contains buttons such as note1, note2, note3.
2) Activity1 which comes with a button on click'g on it will changes the visibility for the above buttons namely note1, note2, note3.

Hey Can any1 help me plz

Activity-1:
public class Activity_2 extends Activity implements OnSeekBarChangeListener
{

```
SeekBar sb1, sb2, sb3, sb4;
Button n1, n2, n3;

private TextView name1, name2, name3, name4, add_row,
          pro_a_e_name1, pro_a_e_name2, pro_a_e_name3, pro_a_e_name4,
          status1, status2, status3, status4;

private ProgressBar prg_br1, prg_br2, prg_br3, prg_br4;
private int prg_br_Status1=0, prg_br_Status2=0, prg_br_Status3=0, prg_br_Status4=0;


/*@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

    n1= (Button) findViewById(R.id.note1);

    Bundle bun1 = getIntent().getExtras();
    int val1 = bun1.getInt("VAL1");
    if(val1==1);
    {
       n1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

}
```

}

Activity-2:
public class note1 extends Activity
{

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.note1);

    final TextView note1_1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.note1_1);

    Bundle extras=getIntent().getExtras();
    String note1 = extras.getString("s1"); 
    note1_1.setText(note1); 

}


public void onBack(View v)
{
    Intent back1= new Intent(note1.this, Activity_2.class);
    Bundle b1= new Bundle();
    String VAL1 = null;
    b1.putInt(VAL1, 1);
    back1.putExtras(b1);
    startActivity(back1);   

}
```

}

This is what i'm trying do apart from changing visiblility
Switching sequence: Act1 to Act2 to Act3 to Act4
Here i am changing visibility while coming back from
Act4 to Act2

Comment: You can do this by either passing data in intent or save data in shared preference and get this data in Oncreate method of second activity.

Comment: Your said problem is different than your coding. Please clarify where you will show note1 visibility? in Activity1 ?

Answer (score 0):

You may try some thing like this ...

```
Button btn;
Button note1;

        btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                note1.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            }
        });
```

If you need to do some thing in other activity simply pass data through intent. Get that value using Bundle on Oncreate() of another activity.

For Ex:

If you pressed note1 button in Activity one then set some default value to it and then pass that value to other activity. By that you will know that which button has been clicked and then simply you can set it's visibility as I mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

Use share preferences for storing visibility of buttons, update preferences from Activity1  and in Activity2 get preferences and update your view in onResume() function.

Answer (score 0):

Here I am writing in pseudo code

Activity 1 :

1. clickOnButton
2. Send some flag (may be 0 or 1) using intent or send your customise data according to your application.

Activity 2 :
 1. Get the flag or your customise data
 2. put it in integer or string according to your datatype
 3. If flag is 0 set visibility else do something

Comment: Sir, but what should i do wen an activity is pointed by two intents. means we can switch to an activity from two other activity. Here am facing same issue. I tried to getbundle from onResume and onRestart method itz not working. can u help in me regarding dis issue...

Comment: @PratikPatil I really understand your pain but I need clear information so that I can help better, right now i am not understand your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

There are many methods you have to achieve what you want to do :

1. Use intent's extra to pass data between activities before calling `startActivity(intent)` method
2. Use `SharedPreference` to store `Button`'s state and use stored values in `Activity2`.
3. Create `public` `static` fields in `Activity1` then use them in `Activity2`'s `onResume()` method to set `Button's` visibility
4. etc ...

Answer (score 0):

Do this on Activity1

```
Button play;

    play = (Button) findViewById(R.id.playId);      

    play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override

    public void onClick(View v) {



    Intent nextActivity = new Intent(Activity1.this, Activity2.class);
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putInt("VAL", 1);

    nextActivity.putExtras(bundle);
    startActivity(nextActivity);

    }

    });
```

on Activity2 do this:

```
Bundle bun=getIntent().getExtras();
int val=bun.getInt("VAL");
 .
 .
 .
if(val==1)
{
   note1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
   note2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
   note3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

It will solve your problem

Comment: I tried dis but just switch'g to activity. Itz nt working. here wen tried to get bundle at other end itz raising exceptoin.

Comment: @PratikPatil it's not happen . I have done this, then I have given you the code. Can you please show your two activites code? it will help me where is your problem.

Comment: Sir, but what should i do wen an activity is pointed by two intents. means we can switch to an activity from two other activity. Here am facing same issue. I tried to getbundle from onResume and onRestart method itz not working. can u help in me regarding dis issue...

Comment: Your code has so many problems. here it's looks like mixup. for better view please post two activities code on your question. So edit your question and post two different activities code. Please also clarify one this Activity2 will show visible button right?

Answer (score 0):

make the button in previous activity "static" and in the next activity on back for example set the viability like                   `previousActivity.Button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);`

i already did it and solve my problem

Comment: does not working. because make null pointer exception for button.